# 2D shaders using original texture color?

Tags: colors, xna, shader

My problem is, that the pixel shader uses the original color of a texture. To be more specific:

My clothes are drawn with the `spriteBatch.Draw()` method. The original texture is white, so I can change it to any color using a different color parameter. But the pixel shader always uses the original white color. Is there any workaround? (Please, no rendering-to-texture tips.)

[image: Example image]

As you can see, without shader clothes have colors. With shader they are white. It's because original texture is white too, but in-game it's colored by Draw() method (Color parameter). I want shader to use new colors.

Comment: @Risal I don't understand what you want to do and what is your problem. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Edited, now it should be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the other method to make use of some parameter is doesn't usually take, you must explicitly pass it and tell it to use it.

Your pixel shader doesn't know what color you are trying to tint the texture with, so you must pass that color as parameter.